# Variable not working properly inside mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named: "m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai" and my sql query is:

```
 $queryac="SELECT * 
           FROM `$actiontable` 
           WHERE (Assignedto LIKE '%$username%' 
                  OR Assignedby='$username')";
```

PHP code for the variables is:

```
 $table=$_GET['id'];

 $actiontable=$table.'-ai';
 id=m+%26amp%3B+m+%2812-11-15+at+11%3A11%29-Ca%3A16%3A20%3A06
```

(I have tried urldecode($_GET['id']), but it does not work either)

Echoed query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai` WHERE (Assignedto LIKE '%mariummalik22@gmail.com%' OR Assignedby='mariummalik22@gmail.com')
```

Table name from mysql: m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai

Error that I get:

```
 Table 'alsonsrn_actionitems.m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai'
```

(Although the table exists)

When I echo $actiontable, I get m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai, which is exactly what my table name is but the query does not work. When I enter the same echoed value manually instead of the variable the query works. What could be the reason of it??

**Note: The same query works for the table names that do not consist of "&"**

Comment: "id" is the ouput of $_GET['id'] ?
Try to [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) $table before putting it in $actiontable

Comment: I have tried it before, it does not work either

Comment: And with rawurldecode? If you put a `var_dump( $actiontable )` the output must be the same string of the table name

Comment: It does not work with rawurldecode either and with var_dump it gives string(44) "m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06-ai"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests.
To get the correct string back I used:

```
$id = 'm+%26amp%3B+m+%2812-11-15+at+11%3A11%29-Ca%3A16%3A20%3A06';
var_dump( html_entity_decode( urldecode( $id ) ) );
```

Output is:

> string(37) "m & m (12-11-15 at 11:11)-Ca:16:20:06"

Try it.

Comment: Your encoded string isn't simply urlencoded, I noticed later the %26amp%3B part, which is entity translated (with htmlentities probably). So you need to decode also the entities